# Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response:

Tags: google-sheets

```
function auto_data_entry() {
  
  
   
  var wrkbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht = wrkbk.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  
  var formURL = "";
  var formData ="";
  var pname ="";
  var email ="";
  var date ="";
  var grade ="";
  var thick ="";
  var width ="";
  var length ="";
  var finish ="";
  var quality ="";
  var quantity="";
  
  var noofRows = 8;
  
  for (i=2;i<=noofRows;i++)
    
  {
  pname = wrkSht.getRange("B"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  email = wrkSht.getRange("C"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  date = wrkSht.getRange("D"+ i).getDisplayValue();  
  grade =wrkSht.getRange("E"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  thick =wrkSht.getRange("F"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  width =wrkSht.getRange("G"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  length =wrkSht.getRange("H"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  finish = wrkSht.getRange("I"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  quality =wrkSht.getRange("J"+ i).getDisplayValue();
  quantity =wrkSht.getRange("K"+ i).getDisplayValue();
 
    
  formURL ="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1_WDcLw2Vkpt6ytssgXXCg9hOmkWn6dYTdKwqPoimUR8/formResponse?&pageHistory=0"
  formData ="&entry.1193833205="+ pname +"&entry.2029914845="+ email +"&entry.849274780="+ date +"&entry.1316665848="+ grade +"&entry.1591447342="+ thick +"&entry.1210651108=" + width +"&entry.298422027="+ length +"&entry.907108031="+ finish +"&entry.1889070012="+ quality +"&entry.1833166722=" + quantity
    
   
  var finalURL = formURL + formData
  
  var options =
      {"method" : "post"
      };
    
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL , options);
    
  }
  
  
  }
```

Trying To fetch Automatic Data from Google sheet to Google Form Response.

Sharing Google FormURL :- "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1_WDcLw2Vkpt6ytssgXXCg9hOmkWn6dYTdKwqPoimUR8/edit#responses"

Google Sheet URL :-https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTO8KhKYLSFssovSWwm3y9ByuVhazz4FImh8uq7UDsA/edit?usp=sharing